# Modify GET request with ?where= before executing it or make double relation

Tags: python, eve

I have an API running on Python-Eve and I have relation setup from one key in one collection to an object in another collection (so key type is relation/ObjectID). My problem is that for some period of time this relation was made based on other keys ("name" instead of "ObjectID") and half of the company wrote automation with that in mind. So they use

`"?where={"region":"name_here"}` and other half
`"?where={"region":"objectID_here"}`.

I was asked if it's possible to make them both working.

As far as I can see - it's not possible to make it in schema definition (to have a relation on two keys) so I tried to modify GET requests on fly (do to something like `"if {"region"}` is string instead of ObjectID then modify it on fly to be ObjectID". I tried app.on_pre_GET event hook but looks like it can't do what I want. I tried to use "lookup" in GET hook but it doesn't work when sending ?where clause (or when where doesn't match anything?) so then I tried to modify url itself but looks like it's not possible to update args list or url (just to get but not save back?)

```
'region':{
    'type':'objectid',
    'data_relation':{
        'resource':'regions',
        'field':'_id',
        'embeddable': True
        },
    }
```

I would love to have a possibility to use? where clause with two possible values for the same key:

```
GET apiurl:/vms?where={"region":"some_region_name"} 
GET apiurl:/vms?where={"region":"5ceeef108941633fc78cdef1"}
```

(both requests should return the same result)

Comment: Please post the code you've tried in your pre_GET hook. You can do this using hooks in fact.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/DavidZisky/5e11ba8cc65f9b5bbdbcfc59335f7bf2

Comment: I see. Problem is that even if you set `lookup['_id'] = <_id from region>` inside the hook, there will still be the `?where` filter in action messing around. In your scenario, could the request params be changed to something like `?region= 5ceeef108941633fc78cdef1` or  `?region=some_region_name` instead of using the `?where`? If so, eve is going to ignore this param but you could use it inside the hook to set the required lookup as you see fit. Just passing directly if already an id, or finding the corresponding id for the label and setting to lookup['_id']

Comment: If we could change the calling URL then it wouldn't be necessary to make this all work - we could simply change all calls which are using name to id then ;)vand that's what I told them at the beginning, but they're pushing me to make some workaround which doesn't require changing all the ansible playbooks they have. We have 23 teams using that API, that's why :( I know "lookup" won't work properly when using "where" that's why I hope to find a way to modify the url itself before executing it (so when user sends the ?where={"region":"core"} API internally changes it to  ?where={"region":"[id]"}

Comment: So the main question is if it's possible to modify the request. Since I can access it: def pre_vms_get_callback(request, lookup): but it looks like only in read only mode. And that make sense since it's just an event hook, right?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot change flask request objects.

Comment: @gcw that's my conclusion as well. Maybe any way to make double relation in python-eve schema then. To somehow make 'field':'_id' or 'field':'name' anyone?